# Python 2.7 list of lists manipulation functionality

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

I am trying to perform several operations on the myList list of lists below and am having some trouble figuring it out. I am very new to Python.

```
myList = [
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC','Break',3275,33,33725102303,296384802,20140107],
['Issue Id','2.Validity check1 for OTC','Break',3308,0,34021487105,0,20140107],
['Issue Id','3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3308,0,34021487105,0,20140107],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST','Break',73376,1,8.24931E+11,44690130,20140107],
['Issue Id','5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73377,0,8.24976E+11,0,20140107],
['Liquidity','1. OTC - Null','Break',7821,0,2.28291E+11,0,20140110],
['Liquidity','2. OTC - Unmapped','Break',7778,43,2.27712E+11,579021732.8,20140110],
['Liquidity','3. RST - Null','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Liquidity','4. RST - Unmapped','Break',334608,512,1.01351E+12,735465433.1,20140110],
['Liquidity','5. RST - Valid','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC','Break',3292,33,32397924450,306203929,20140110],
['Issue Id','2.Validity check1 for OTC','Break',3325,0,32704128379,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3325,0,32704128379,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST','Break',73594,3,8.5352E+11,69614602,20140110],
['Issue Id','5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73597,0,8.5359E+11,0,20140110],
['Unlinked Silver ID','DQ','Break',3201318,176,20000000,54974.33386,20140101],
['Missing GCI','DQ','Break',3201336,158,68000000,49351.9588,20140101],
['Missing Book','DQ','Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],
['Matured Trades','DQ','Break',3201006,488,1371000000,152428.8348,20140101],
['Illiquid Trades','1.Completeness Check for range','Break',43122,47,88597695671,54399061.43,20140107],
['Illiquid Trades','2.Completeness Check for non','Break',39033,0,79133622401,0,20140107]
]
```

I am trying to get the result below but do not know how to do so:

```
newList = [
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3275,33,33725102303,296384802,20140107],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73376,1,8.24931E+11,44690130,20140107],
['Liquidity','1. OTC - Null','Break:2. OTC - Unmapped','Break',7821 0,2.28291E+11,0,20140110],
['Liquidity','3. RST - Null:4. RST - Unmapped:5. RST - Valid','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3292,33,32397924450,306203929,20140110],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST:5. RST - Valid','Break',73594,3,8.5352E+11,69614602,20140110],
['Unlinked Silver ID','DQ','Break',3201318,176,20000000,54974.33386,20140101],
['Missing GCI','DQ','Break',3201336,158,68000000,49351.9588,20140101],
['Missing Book','DQ Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],
['Matured Trades','DQ','Break',3201006,488,1371000000,152428.8348,20140101],
['Illiquid Trades','1.Completeness Check for range','Break',43122,47,88597695671,54399061.43,20140107],
['Illiquid Trades','2.Completeness Check for non','Break',39033,0,79133622401,0,20140107]
]
```

Rules to create newList. Create a new list in the newList list of lists if the values in the lists meet the following conditions:

1. multiple lists that match on `myList[i][0]` and `myList[i][7]` but with have (1) sums of `myList[i][3]` and `myList[i][4]` and (2) sums of `myList[i][5]` and `myList[i][6]` that are different from each other are just listed as is in newList
2. if multiple lists match on both `myList[i][0]` (this is the type) and `myList[i][7]` (this is the date) are the same then create a new list for each set of lists with mathcing `myList[i][0]` and `myList[i][7]` that have (1) sums of `myList[i][3]` and `myList[i][4]` and (2) sums of `myList[i][5]` and `myList[i][6]` that are different from the other lists with mathcing `myList[i][0]` and `myList[i][7]`. I also am trying to concatenate `myList[i][1]` separated by a ':' for all those lists with matching `myList[i][0]` and `myList[i][7]` and with sums of `myList[i][3]` + `myList[i][4]` and `myList[i][5]` + `myList[i][6]` that match. So essentially for this case only those lists in `myList` with sums of `myList[i][3]` + `myList[i][4]` and `myList[i][5]` + `myList[i][6]` are different from the other lists are then listed in newList.

The above newList illustrates these results I am trying to achieve. If anyone has any ideas how to do this they would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: My head exploded trying to read your specification.

Comment: You might want to think of defining custom classes or something to organize this. If I had to work on your code, I would have no idea what is going on.

Comment: My head is broken here too, but I think you'll want to come up with a different data structure.  Have you learned about `dict` yet?

Comment: Doesn't help your `myList` has a syntax error.  (I just fixed it)

Comment: Haha, good point. I will try to better organize it. You are right now that I read it - I could have explained it better and more simply as well. It does not appear that the orginal post can be edited once after submission. Thank you anyway for reading through it!

Comment: You can edit the post by clicking "edit".

Comment: @interjay I sometimes find it useful to use `[edit]` as that also puts a direct link in your commment... eg: `You can [edit] the post`... (sorry if you were already aware of that - just thought I'd mention it in case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to write .

```
myList = [
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC','Break',3275,33,33725102303,296384802,20140107],
['Issue Id','2.Validity check1 for OTC','Break',3308,0,34021487105,0,20140107],
['Issue Id','3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3308,0,34021487105,0,20140107],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST','Break',73376,1,8.24931E+11,44690130,20140107],
['Issue Id','5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73377,0,8.24976E+11,0,20140107],
['Liquidity','1. OTC - Null','Break',7821,0,2.28291E+11,0,20140110],
['Liquidity','2. OTC - Unmapped','Break',7778,43,2.27712E+11,579021732.8,20140110],
['Liquidity','3. RST - Null','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Liquidity','4. RST - Unmapped','Break',334608,512,1.01351E+12,735465433.1,20140110],
['Liquidity','5. RST - Valid','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC','Break',3292,33,32397924450,306203929,20140110],
['Issue Id','2.Validity check1 for OTC','Break',3325,0,32704128379,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3325,0,32704128379,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST','Break',73594,3,8.5352E+11,69614602,20140110],
['Issue Id','5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73597,0,8.5359E+11,0,20140110],
['Unlinked Silver ID','DQ','Break',3201318,176,20000000,54974.33386,20140101],
['Missing GCI','DQ','Break',3201336,158,68000000,49351.9588,20140101],
['Missing Book','DQ','Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],
['Matured Trades','DQ','Break',3201006,488,1371000000,152428.8348,20140101],
['Illiquid Trades','1.Completeness Check for range','Break',43122,47,88597695671,54399061.43,20140107],
['Illiquid Trades','2.Completeness Check for non','Break',39033,0,79133622401,0,20140107]
]



newList = [
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3275,33,33725102303,296384802,20140107],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST','Break',73376,1,8.24931E+11,44690130,20140107],

#  ['Liquidity','1. OTC - Null','Break',7821,0,2.28291E+11,0,20140110],
#  ['Liquidity','2. OTC - Unmapped','Break',7778,43,2.27712E+11,579021732.8,20140110],
#       2.28291E+11 + 0  !=  2.27712E+11 + 579021732.8 , so  I used ceil. 
['Liquidity','1. OTC - Null','Break:2. OTC - Unmapped','Break',7821,0,2.28291E+11,0,20140110],

['Liquidity','3. RST - Null:4. RST - Unmapped:5. RST - Valid','Break',335120,0,1.01425E+12,0,20140110],
['Issue Id','1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC','Break',3292,33,32397924450,306203929,20140110],
['Issue Id','4.Completeness for RST:5. RST - Valid','Break',73594,3,8.5352E+11,69614602,20140110],
['Unlinked Silver ID','DQ','Break',3201318,176,20000000,54974.33386,20140101],
['Missing GCI','DQ','Break',3201336,158,68000000,49351.9588,20140101],
['Missing Book','DQ','Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],
['Matured Trades','DQ','Break',3201006,488,1371000000,152428.8348,20140101],
['Illiquid Trades','1.Completeness Check for range','Break',43122,47,88597695671,54399061.43,20140107],
['Illiquid Trades','2.Completeness Check for non','Break',39033,0,79133622401,0,20140107]
]

import math

def create():
  index = 0
  prevKey = (myList[index][0], myList[index][7])
  sumOf3rd4th = myList[index][3] + myList[index][4]
  sumOf5th6th = myList[index][5] + myList[index][6]
  answerList = []
  answerList.append(myList[index])
  index += 1

  ceil56 = lambda x : math.ceil( x / 10000000)

  while index < len(myList):
    if prevKey == (myList[index][0], myList[index][7]) and \
        sumOf3rd4th == myList[index][3] + myList[index][4] and \
        ceil56(sumOf5th6th) == ceil56(myList[index][5] + myList[index][6]):
        # sumOf5th6th == myList[index][5] + myList[index][6]:
          answerList[-1][1] += ":" + myList[index][1]
    else:
        answerList.append(myList[index])
        prevKey = (myList[index][0], myList[index][7])
        sumOf3rd4th = myList[index][3] + myList[index][4]
        sumOf5th6th = myList[index][5] + myList[index][6]
    index += 1
  return answerList

myNewList = create()
print myNewList

# [
# ['Issue Id', '1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC', 'Break', 3275, 33, 33725102303L, 296384802, 20140107], 
# ['Issue Id', '4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST', 'Break', 73376, 1, 824931000000.0, 44690130, 20140107], 
# ['Liquidity', '1. OTC - Null:2. OTC - Unmapped', 'Break', 7821, 0, 228291000000.0, 0, 20140110], 
# ['Liquidity', '3. RST - Null:4. RST - Unmapped:5. RST - Valid', 'Break', 335120, 0, 1014250000000.0, 0, 20140110],
# ['Issue Id', '1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC', 'Break', 3292, 33, 32397924450L, 306203929, 20140110], 
# ['Issue Id', '4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST', 'Break', 73594, 3, 853520000000.0, 69614602, 20140110], 
# ['Unlinked Silver ID', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201318, 176, 20000000, 54974.33386, 20140101], 
# ['Missing GCI', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201336, 158, 68000000, 49351.9588, 20140101], 
# ['Missing Book', 'DQ', 'Break', 3192720, 8774, 3001000000L, 2740595.484, 20140101], 
# ['Matured Trades', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201006, 488, 1371000000, 152428.8348, 20140101], 
# ['Illiquid Trades', '1.Completeness Check for range', 'Break', 43122, 47, 88597695671L, 54399061.43, 20140107], 
# ['Illiquid Trades', '2.Completeness Check for non', 'Break', 39033, 0, 79133622401L, 0, 20140107]
# ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it is completely unclear as to what you are trying to do. But I think this should help you accomplish it.

Now, it seems to me that we can sort this list on the key `(elem[0], elem[7])`. If we do this, then we would only ever be merging neighbors.

If that's true, then we can do the sort, and then apply a reduction function:

```
def reduction(result, rhs):
    if len(result) == 0:
        return [rhs]
    lhs = result[-1]

    if lhs[0] != rhs[0]:
        return result + [rhs]
    if lhs[7] != rhs[7]:
        return result + [rhs]

    # Compute the new lhs object
    lhs[1] += ":" + rhs[1]
    lhs[3] += rhs[3]
    lhs[4] += rhs[4]

    # Don't append the rhs object
    return result

# Sort the list such that we are only going to be merging neighbors.
myList.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[7]))

# Apply a reduction
newList = functools.reduce(reduction, myList, [])
```

This reduction function is **not** what you want, but that's because I don't understand exactly what you want. In particular, this code produces:

```
['Illiquid Trades', '1.Completeness Check for range:2.Completeness Check for non', 'Break', 82155, 47, 88597695671, 54399061.43, 20140107]
['Issue Id', '1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC:4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST', 'Break', 156644, 34, 33725102303, 296384802, 20140107]
['Issue Id', '1.Completeness for OTC:2.Validity check1 for OTC:3.Validity check2 for OTC:4.Completeness for RST:5.Validity check1 for RST', 'Break', 157133, 36, 32397924450, 306203929, 20140110]
['Liquidity', '1. OTC - Null:2. OTC - Unmapped:3. RST - Null:4. RST - Unmapped:5. RST - Valid', 'Break', 1020447, 555, 228291000000.0, 0, 20140110]
['Matured Trades', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201006, 488, 1371000000, 152428.8348, 20140101]
['Missing Book', 'DQ', 'Break', 3192720, 8774, 3001000000, 2740595.484, 20140101]
['Missing GCI', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201336, 158, 68000000, 49351.9588, 20140101]
['Unlinked Silver ID', 'DQ', 'Break', 3201318, 176, 20000000, 54974.33386, 20140101]
```

**Note:** Assuming that the premise holds (you are only merging elements that you can easily sort next to one another), you can fairly easily fix the conditions to not merge objects, and fairly easily fix the conditions to create the new merged object.

Comment: Hi, sorry `['Missing Book','DQ Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],` was supposed to be `['Missing Book','DQ','Break',3192720,8774,3001000000,2740595.484,20140101],]` - forgot to put the comma between `'DQ','Break'`. Thank you very much for your help, I will try this out now.